# sum columns of a data frame depending on the category the observations belong to

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a dataframe as such:

```
     Response  Spent    Saved
1       Yes     100      25 
2       Yes     200      50 
3       No       20       2
4       No       13       3
```

I would like to sum up the amounts Spent and Saved, depending on the Response, ie:

```
     Response  Spent    Saved
1       Yes     300      75 
2       No      33       5
```

Right now, I am using a hackneyed approach, where I subset the dataframe into 2 new dataframes, convert the 2nd and 3rd columns into numeric data, do a colSums on each column individually, then save the outputs into a vector, then create a new dataframe....suffice to say it is a terrible approach.

How could I do this is a more effective manner?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `?aggregate`

If your data.frame is `DF`, following should do what you want.

```
aggregate(. ~ Response, data = DF, FUN = sum)
##   Response Spent Saved
## 1       No    33     5
## 2      Yes   300    75
```

Comment: Aha!  So in English:    "Aggregate everything, with respect to Response, where the dataframe is DF, and the aggregation function is summation."  Perfect!